# SQL Server + ODBC + QT : Showing BLANK records after transaction

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

I am using : QT 5.0.2 + MinGW 4.7 + 32 bits + ODBC driver + Windows 7 (32) + SQL Server 2012 Express

The “problem”:

1) I’ve got one window showing records from a database table.

2) If somewhere in the application, I have to update the database without using ‘transactions’ everything works ok.

3) If somewhere in the application, I have to update the database using ‘transactions’ the records showing in the window (1) (*) disappeared and become blank records.

NOTE (*): If I’ve got more windows (MDI) showing several tables, all windows, all tables records go BLANK simultaneously.

I decided to check with “SQL Server Profiler” what happens on Server side when someone uses QSqlTableModel\QSqlQueryModel and I think I have “found” the (my) problem on Server but I am not sure where exactly is the problem on my / QT side:

1) when the window opens, QSqlTableModel\QSqlQueryModel (I think) creates a cursor “exec sp_cursoropen 180150003” on server

2) retrieves some records “exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003”

3) if the window repaint/refresh retrieves again some records “exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003”

4) after executing the “transaction” someone (who?) closes the cursor being used (I think) by QSqlTableModel\QSqlQueryModel “exec sp_cursorclose 180150003”

5) after that, there are no more entries of “exec sp_cursorfetch….” That’s why (I think) the QTableView show BLANK records.

NOTE (*): When using MDI subwindows showing each one of them a completely different and unrelated table. After the “transaction” all subwindows/QTableView automatically show BLANK records. I’ve checked with “SQL Server Profiler” and after the “transaction” there are as many “exec sp_cursorfetch” as opened subwindows.

It seems that all “cursors” are automatically closed, no matter if they are related with the updates (single table) being made.

Assuming that the “problem” is that\those “exec sp_cursorclose”, does anyone have an idea why that\those (exec sp_cursorclose) automatically happens:

- Is it a ODBC (generally speaking) limitation?
- Is it a ODBC (QT implementation) limitation?
- Is it a ODBC (MSSQL implementation) limitation?
- Is it a QSqlxxxxxx implementation/limitation?

What am I missing here?

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are your sql insert's values and variables you want to enter into the server correct?
I know that this has nothing to do with what you are asking but small errors in mysql servers can cause others to occur. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am pretty sure that SQL syntax is correct.  If it helps the full story behind my question + a example of a small test application demonstrating this situation is available here :
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/28390/

I was not expecting this behavior and so far I was unable to find an explanation for it. My hope is that someone with some expertise in ODBC or SQL Server or QT could help me understand or even fix this situation.